# Parse HTML to get all img src Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, zillow

I am trying to get all the image src on the URL , but I am stuck on error " The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.". Please help.

```
function getimageurls(){

  var url ="https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/Baltimore-MD-21224/36431822_zpid/66834_rid/globalrelevanceex_sort/39.317168,-76.41386,39.2393,-76.64835_rect/11_zm/";

  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

  Logger.log(html)

}
```

Comment: Zillow has an API  [Link to Zillow API](https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/APIOverview.htm)  They probably don't want you scraping their site.  You should use the API.  The error that you are getting may not have anything to do with Apps Script.  If that's the case, you aren't going to be able to resolve this problem with different code.  You need to know what the correct URL is.  That's an issue specific to Zillow, not Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

This will find the img lines in the view as source for that URL.  I just did it UltraEdit.

```
<img src=".*?"
```